# Sony smartwatch create 2 extensions with only 1 app

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm developing and smartwatch application and I wonder if I can create 2 extensions on the same app. I mean, I want my Android app to create 2 smartwatch extensions, instead of only one as usual. Could you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not possible.  Is there a reason you don't want to have 2 separate apks?  It would probably be better to have two apks in case the user only wants one extension and not the other since they would not be able to uninstall just a single extension.